# Binding Rich Text Box ScaleTransform to slider inside User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have an instance of a user control in my project that contains a slider. I would like to bind the ScaleTransform of a RichTextBox control to the value of the slider but I do not know how to properly reference it. The user control is called toolbar and the slider inside it is called Scale this is what I have tried so far:

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="body" 
                 SelectionChanged="body_SelectionChanged"
                 SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True"
                 AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True"
                 BorderThickness="0 2 0 0">
        <RichTextBox.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=toolbar.Scale, Path=Value}" ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=toolbar.Scale, Path=Value}"/>
        </RichTextBox.LayoutTransform>
    </RichTextBox>
```

I have also tried doing it in the .cs file since I'm having trouble with the binding but haven't had any luck figuring out how to actually set the transform values once my slider event has been fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reference names inside other controls, they are in another name-scope. If you need the slider value bind it to a property of the `UserControl`.

`UserControl` code (whatever that class may be called in your case):

```
<!-- ToolBar.xaml -->
<UserControl ...
             Name="control">
    <!-- ... -->
    <Slider Value="{Binding ScaleValue, ElementName=control}" ... />
    <!-- ... -->
</UserControl>
```

```
// ToolBar.xaml.cs
public partial class ToolBar : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScaleValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ScaleValue", typeof(double), typeof(ToolBar));
    public double ScaleValue
    {
        { get { return (double)GetValue(ScaleValueProperty); }
        { set { SetValue(ScaleValueProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

New binding code:

```
<ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=toolbar, Path=ScaleValue}" ... />
```

Comment: I have done this and saved the value inside of a property called _documentScale, how do I then bind to that value?

Comment: @JesseCarter: You should properly [register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.register.aspx) a [dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx). (Also the name reeks of a field, you can only bind to public properties)

Comment: I'm confused about the first part with the UserControl. Do I register the Slider Value inside the User Control xaml or the MainWindow xaml that implements the user control. User Control xaml does not contain a name, only a class

Comment: @JesseCarter: What? A UserControl should have a .xaml file for its markup and a .xaml.cs file for the code behind, you would register the property in the .xaml.cs file, then bind the slider to that property in the the .xaml file. You would name the UserControl element to reference it in the `Slider.Value` binding.

Comment: Sorry I got myself confused there. The slider is zooming in and out now but I have completely lost the ability to type in the rich text box.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14602/discussion-between-jesse-carter-and-h-b)

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I think I figured it out. You're a life saver